# using hostgator on Safari browser jquery doesnt work

Tags: jquery, safari

My website, http://necesitio.com.mx using HostGator on Safari browser jQuery doesn't work, while the same site on a GoDaddy server does work properly. http://ericzwanenburg.com/proyectosweb/necesitio/2/

Anyone any idea what it could be?

As well using the HostGator version the testimonial images don't show.

Comment: works fine on goDaddy + safari browser? All jquery versions etc are the same?

Comment: Any errors from the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

I saw your website and I'm wondering if the jQuery doesn't work with the animations or with process you have like send forms or something.

I've tried your website with safari and seems to be working properly. Did you tried with another computer? Maybe cookies or something are not allowing their functionality.

Otherwise, please specify which part of the website isn't working
Oh, and if you rather a "Spanish Answer" please tell me, I'm from Mexico.

Greetings!

Comment: Peter, you where right.. Its the cookies...  Thanks for your help! Saludos desde Cancun

Comment: Answers should be given only in English as well as comments, please use Stackoverflow in other languages if you wish to proceed with answers or comments in different languages.

Comment: Glad to help amigo! Greetings from León, Gto. MX